# Triggering custom view functionality from a route

Tags: ember.js

I'm having trouble triggering custom functionality in my view, given a certain route.

Normally, if I visited /posts/1, and my view had this in it

```
{{ id }}
```

the id would update, whether I navigated to the route from within my app, or visited /posts/1 for the first time on a page refresh.

But what if the template is not as straight-forward? For example, I'm using a datepicker that has its own API to update the display. So, when the data changes, I need to call

```
this.$('#dp').datepicker('setDate', month)
```

I have this working if the route changes from within the app, but what if the user starts out on one of these routes? I tried adding a custom method on my view

```
App.DatepickerView = Ember.View.extend({
    didInsertElement: function() {
        ....
    },

    setMonth: function(month) {
        this.$('#dp').datepicker('setDate', month.get('id'));
    }
});
```

and hooking into the route like this:

```
App.MonthRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
    setupController: function(controller) {
        App.DatepickerView.setMonth(controller.get('model'));
    }
})
```

but I'm getting that `setMonth` is undefined. What's the right way to go about this?

**Update:** Here's the template for the Datepicker:

```
{{#view App.DatepickerView }}
  <div class="filter-section">
    <div id="dp" class="input-prepend date">
      <span class="add-on"><strong>Month</strong></span>
      <input class="span2" type="text" placeholder="Select a month">
    </div>
  </div>
{{/view}}
```

Comment: Can you show the template that use the App.DatepickerView?

Answer (score 1):

I think you could approach this in a slightly different way. I'd pass the bound content to the date picker view rather than trying to call a method on the view directly. I use the syncDates method to do the actual work of mapping my value to the JQUI widget (your needs may vary slightly here).

Within template:

```
{{view App.DateView valueBinding="some_date"}}
```

View code:

```
App.DateView = Em.View.extend
  template: Em.Handlebars.compile '<input type="text" /><input type="hidden" {{bindAttr value="view.value"}} />'
  syncDates: ( ->
    if (elm = @$('input[type=text]') ).length && d = @get 'value'
      d = d.split '-'
      elm.val d[1] + '/' + d[2] + '/' + d[0]
  ).observes 'value'

  didInsertElement: ->
    return unless $.datepicker
    @$('input[type=text]').datepicker
      altField:   @$ 'input[type=hidden]'
      format:     'mm/dd/yy'
      altFormat:  'yy-mm-dd'

      onSelect: (dateText, inst) =>
        @set 'value', @$('input[type=hidden]').val()
```

Comment: how exactly does valueBinding work? That's keeping a property named 'value' on the view in sync with a property named 'value' on the controller?

Comment: The DateView has a property called value. I could have also called it bobBinding and then in DateView observed bob (ie. the word value is just a convention as this is a text field and the html attribute used is called value). So valueBinding="some_date" will pass the property from your controller called "some_date" to the DateView and the bindings will keeps things in sync.

Comment: Hmm...so how would I get the id of the active model from the controller? `valueBinding="id"`?

Comment: I can't get this working. I need a view in my Application template to respond to the selected model in the ModelController. I'm finding this difficult!

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the jquery ui datepicker and need the entire calendar I recommend to do the following:

Create a date picker field

```
App.DatePickerField = Ember.TextField.extend({  
    didInsertElement: function() {
      this.$().datepicker();
    }
});
```

Update your template to use the view

```
 <div class="filter-section">
    <div id="dp" class="input-prepend date">
      <span class="add-on"><strong>Month</strong></span>
      {{view App.DatePickerField valueBinding="yourDate"}}
      <input class="span2" type="text" placeholder="Select a month">
    </div>
  </div>
```

Or if you just want to bind the month, with select tag

```
App.months = ["JAN", "FEV", "MAR" ...]

<div class="filter-section">
    <div id="dp" class="input-prepend date">
      <span class="add-on"><strong>Month</strong></span>
      {{view Ember.Select contentBinding="App.months" selectionBinding="yourMonth" class="span2" prompt="Select a month" }}
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: I don't see how this could work, I need to be able to call a Javascript function when the value changes.

Comment: I had understood that you needed to bind the value from the datepicker to your model.

Comment: No, I have that working. What I need is, suppose we load index#/Jan-2013. I need to update the datepicker to display 'Jan 2013'.